# You done/finished already?/You already done/finished?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I'm out eating with a friend. The friend suddenly places his knife and fork to indicate that he's done eating, even though he hasn't even finished half of the food on his plate. How should I phrase the question if I'm surprised that he's already done eating without it will sound like he finished all his food? (Please don't use my suggestions if they aren't good)

You done/finished already? / You already done/finished?

Comment: We say colloquially: Are you done eating? FOR: Have you finished eating?

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Yes, the these would mean that your friend is "done/finished *eating*," not that the food has all been eaten, mainly because the person is the the subject of the sentence. If I get bored of a chess game and say "I'm done with this," I mean that *my participation* is done, not the game.

The usages of "you" and "done" and "finished" get a little complicated here, especially in a conversational (informal) setting. The short version is that all your examples are okay.

- "Done" is a participle. In a formal setting, you would ask "**Are** you done" (or, with the contraction, "**You're** done?").
- **But** it's quite common in casual conversation to drop the *'re* in *you're*. "You done?" is perfectly idiomatic.
- The plot thickens: "You finished" might be this colloquial use of a preposition, *or* it might be simple past tense. Either is okay.